# Is there a jQuery equivalent to prototype's defer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Is there a jQuery equivalent to prototype's defer?

I'm looking for something that will delay the execution of a script until all of the scripts in the page are finished executing.

Thanks!

---

PART II:
Is there any way to see if there are other setTimeouts in the queue and delay execution until after they fire?  I see in the comments that sometimes setTimeout of 0 or 1 doesn't matter because it's unpredictable as to which will fire first.

Thanks again!

#### Update to answer

I found a bug in the code that I was using from the answer accepted below. The slice call needs to work on 0, not 1 since in the Prototype core code, it's accepting an extra parameter for the amount of time to wait (0.01).  The final method then becomes:

```
Function.prototype.deferFunc = function() {
   var __method = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
   return window.setTimeout(function() {
      return __method.apply(__method, args);
   }, 0.01);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which `defer` you are referring to? The only one I know is not specific to Prototype.

Comment: Ah, I assume you mean this one. http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/defer

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the js library prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `defer` does is execute the function inside `window.setTimeout` with timeout of 0.

You can implement it like this I am sure:

```
Function.prototype.defer = function() {
        var __method = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return window.setTimeout(function() {
          return __method.apply(__method, args);
        }, 0);
      }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76TqQ/)

Comment: I decided to go with this implementation since it can accept methods with parameters.  It also seems closest to the implementation used by prototype (the library).  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!

Comment: BTW, I also want to verify that you DO need the changes that Andy E suggests above!

Comment: When I try this I get an error that says:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'apply'

(This is using Strelok's code with Andy's changes).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the basic version available in vanilla JavaScript for most purposes, [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  //do something
}, 0);
```

A similar queuing mechanism jQuery uses for animations are the callbacks and the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function (which uses `setTimeout()` underneath).

Comment: +1 for vanilla JS.  The only difference is that *defer()* can accept variables as arguments that will be stored in their current state, kind of like a combination of *setTimeout()* and *bind()*.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily implement it:

```
Function.prototype.defer=function() {
    setTimeout(this, 0);
}
```

and here's a test:

```
var testFunc=function() {
    alert('first');
}
testFunc.defer();
alert('second');//first the browser will run this line, then will execute the above defered one.
```

Comment: Setting the timer to 1 won't add the callback to the thread queue until 1ms later, setting the timer to 0 will add it to the thread queue immediately.

Comment: Not correct Andy E, all browsers have a varying minimum timeout restriction and furthermore, the timeout will never be exact as it will wait for any script thats executing untill there's an opening.

Comment: @BGerrissen - @Andy is correct, for example try this in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QJdEg/ Notice the `setTimeout(func, 1)` gets queued *after* the `setTimeout(func, 0)`, so setting it to 1 isn't the same, as a timeout of 0 can still jump in front, depending on the browser.

Comment: Prototype actually uses 10ms, not 0, internally. Their docs are a touch misleading.